# country code conversion issue in jvector map

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I am trying to use jvectormap and it takes input in the format ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country codes.

My input is in the form of country names. I have checked for name to code converters in JavasSript, but there are not any.

I was wondering how the conversion is possible, so that I can match my input with the jvectormap input. Any ideas?

Check the link: http://jsfiddle.net/sprugman/fkRnC/7/

The jvectormap input model is like

```
var gdpData = {
"US": 25,
"CA": 50,
"RU": 100,
"AO": 200,
"AG": 200,
"AR": 400,
"BR":200 
 };
```

and also is google [geochart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) better than this one??

Comment: Not sure if this will be possible. Is there any way your input can be the codes instead?

Comment: i searched for the converters online... I can alter my input if I knew what the codes of all those countries are...

Comment: Could use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Officially_assigned_code_elements

Comment: does it cover all the present countries??

Comment: You could use the official site if you worried. Looks to be at http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/iso-3166-1_decoding_table.htm

Comment: ok thanks..will try this.. and wil surely giv u a feedback..

Comment: Would you be interested in map data keyed off of country names instead of alpha-2, or do you want to convert your data into a data set keyed off of alpha-2? It would be helpful if you posted a sample of your data as well.

Comment: @MadsHansen  the way my input for the graphmap is of the form.. "usa" "uk" "australia" "china"

Comment: Well, you need a common key in order to be able to select the items. You could customize your map or your data set keys, but at some point need a mapping between your country name values and the map data. What vocabulary is your data, or how were the country "names" decided upon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a new map keyed off the country names using the `world_mill_en` map and the country name values from the `name` properties:

```
//Clone the world map that uses ISO-2 keys
var countriesByName = $.extend(true, {}, jvm.WorldMap.maps['world_mill_en']);

countriesByName.paths = {}; //clear the paths

$.each(jvm.WorldMap.maps['world_mill_en'].paths, function(key, obj){
   //create new path entries, keyed by the country name
   countriesByName.paths[obj.name] = obj; 
});  

//Add this new data map, to be loaded
$.fn.vectorMap('addMap', 'world_mill_en_byName',countriesByName);
```

Then load your data keyed off country names and reference the newly created map:

```
//data with country name as key
var gdpData = {
    "United States of America": 25,
    "Canada": 50,
    "Russia": 100,
    "Angola": 200,
    "Argentina": 400
};

$(function() {
    $('#map').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill_en_byName', //load up the map with country name as key
        backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
        regionStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: '#cccccc'
            }
        },
        series: {
            regions: [{
                values: gdpData,
                scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
                min: 0,
                max: 400,
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'}]
        },
        hoverOpacity: 0.7,
        hoverColor: false
    });

    var mapObj = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
    var steps = 4;
    for (var i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
        var val = 400 / steps * i;
        var color = mapObj.series.regions[0].scale.getValue(val);
        $('#key').append('<div style="background-color:' + color + ';">' + val + ' - ' + color + '</div>');
    }
});
```

Applied to the jsfiddle that you had posted: http://jsfiddle.net/hansenmc/fkRnC/8/​

Comment: Again, the problem is that there is a big chance that many names of the countries won't be the same as in OP's data source. This is why the simple and common standard is used to identify countries.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common request, but it's really hard to solve this problem once and forever just because there are numerous variants to write the names of the countries and even country region. So the solution here could be converting of the names of the countries to country codes using data from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) or any other source.